# Network Interface not config in 12.04 LST USB boot

Tags: 12.04, networking

Booting 12.04 LST from USB 0n Toshiba Laptop

Built with Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.3.6 from 12.04.2-desktop-AMD64 on Windows 8

`lspci` returns:

```
01:00 Ethernet Cntrl " Atheros " Gigabit Ethernet
02:00 Network Cntrl  " Realteck " Device 8723
```

Realteck is the wireless PCI device

`iwconfig` returns:

```
l0 .... Missing the above ( ie. no eth(n) & wlan(n) )
```

Comment: Here is a post that I believe explains your dilemma. Please verify with lspci -nn that you have the exact same devices. If you are willing to install 13.04, drivers for both devices are included by default. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2050126